# Segfault when trying to printf large char[]

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

The following code is segfaulting on me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const int MEMSIZE = 1024*1024*10;
    char memblock[MEMSIZE];
    memblock[10] = '\0';

    printf("%s", memblock);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there some size limit on character arrays? I've forgotten all my C, am I doing something stupid here?

Comment: Coincidentally, this is a case of stack overflow (or underflow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no limit on the size of char arrays as such but stack sizes will be relatively constrained compared to available heap memory.  You're probably overflowing the stack here.  You could try making `memblock` static

```
static char memblock[MEMSIZE];
```

or allocating it dynamically

```
char* memblock = malloc(MEMSIZE);
if (memblock == NULL) {
    printf("Error: failed to allocate %d byte buffer\n", MEMSIZE);
    return -1;
}
memblock[10] = '\0';
printf("%s", memblock);
free(memblock);
```

Comment: It is better to check the value returned to `memblock` before writing to it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun True.  I'd skipped this for brevity but that was possibly the wrong call here.  I've added the check now.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. For others reading this, declaring memblock as static required me to `#define MEMSIZE 1024*1024*10`. Allocating dynamically works fine but I got a warning until I did `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 5):

Discover what's your max stack size with this small program, and check if your array is bigger

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main ()
{
    struct rlimit rl;
    int result = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);
    printf("max stack size: %u\n", rl.rlim_cur);
}
```

result on my host

```
max stack size: 10485760
```

Local variables are stored into stack and, obviously, they can't be bigger than his max size

Comment: +1, great info. On my Ubuntu VM this is 8MB, which can also be found via `ulimit -s`